# Django ORM grouping by hour excluding minutes

Tags: django-orm

Hello I'm trying to grouping a django query by hour excluding minutes.

Let me show a example:

```py
[...]
date_example = models.DateTimeField("My Example", blank=True, null=True)
quantity = models.IntegerField("Quantity", default=1)
[...]
```

In my head this example should work:

```py
ModelExample.objects.values("date_example__hour").annotate(total_quantity=Sum("quantity"))
```

But the output takes into account minutes and seconds.

Is there a way to group by hour excluding minutes and seconds?

Example: the group has 7 hours inside (7:00, 7:20, 7:45)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`ExtractHour`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractHour) for that:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models import ExtractHour

ModelExample.objects.values(
    hour=ExtractHour('date_example')
).annotate(
    total_quantity=Sum('quantity')
).order_by('hour')
```

Comment: Hey @Willen thanx a lot. Works fine =)